# Is this a sufficient proof of complex differentiability?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Say you're trying to show that a function $f$ with complex arguments is complex differentiable at some point $a$, you want to show that the limit
$$
\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+c)-f(a)}{c}
$$
exists and is the same regardless of the approach of $c$ to $0$. Now, consider the expression
$$
\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}\left|\left|\frac{f(a+c)-f(a)}{c}-\frac{g(a,c)}{c}\right|\right|=\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}\frac{\|\|f(a+c)-f(a)-g(a,c)\|\|}{\|c\|}.
$$
If the above limit is shown to be $0$ then is this sufficient to prove that $f$ is complex differentiable at $a$ with the derivative being $\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(a,c)}{c}$? (Provided that last limit is consistent across all approaches to $0$).

My thinking is that if the limit of the norm is $0$ then the limit
$$
\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+c)-f(a)}{c}-\frac{g(a,c)}{c}=\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+c)-f(a)}{c}-\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(a,c)}{c}
$$
must also be $0$, implying the result. Is my reasoning sound?

I ask becausein a textbook I'm reading, a function is shown to be differentiable on some open set via an expression of this form, however the author does not specify complex differentiability and I want to verify whether the function is also holomorphic on the set (Murphy, C*-Algebras and Operator Theory, Lemma 1.2.4 via Theorem 1.2.3).

Comment: By definition a norm is $0$ only at $0$. Also the norm is continuous and hence you can pass the limit through the norm. This justifies your argument.

Comment: Thanks! I'm self teaching this stuff from a physics background so I want to make sure I'm not being wrong-headed about things.

Comment: To be clear, your argument only works in the case that we know at least one of $\lim _{c\to 0} \frac{f(a+c)-f(a)}{c}$  or $\lim_{c\to 0} \frac{g(a,c)}{c}$ exists.

Comment: More generally, in every normed space, $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x) = c$ is defined as $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} ||f(x)-c|| = 0$, so you are literally just using the definition of the limit in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: In the specific case I'm concerned with the $g(a,c)$ is simply a function of $a$ multiplied by $c$ which is just cancelled by the denominator. I appreciate the warning though, one must be careful with these things.

Comment: Assuming $f$ is complex-valued: The condition "$g(a,c) = c\phi(a)$" matters (and is sufficient to imply $f$ is differentiable at $a$ with $f'(a)=\phi(a)$); otherwise we could take $g(a,c)=f(a+c)-f(a)$, for example (from which we conclude nothing).